# Regular Expression extracted from DB not matching the value

Tags: java, mysql, regex

In short:

```
String regExp = "\\w{3}-\\d{3}";
System.out.println("REF-123".matches(regExp)); // IS TRUE

// Exact same regular expression extracted from the database: \\w{3}-\\d{3}
regExp = resultSet.getString("regex");
System.out.println("REF-123".matches(regExp)); // IS FALSE
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

**Sorted:**

Double slash in java string escaping a previous slash, in DB however it doesn’t need to be saved with double slash.

Comment: voting to close as unclear

Comment: What exactly is unclear?

Comment: we do not know what is regularExpressionExtractedFromDB ,

Comment: Probably your DB string value is escaped twice (or 4 times, according to perspective).

Comment: There is a regular expression saved in Mysql data base, I extract it, try matching it to the value - the result is false, when doing print out of that regular expression to see what am i actually getting (as first thought) I copy what I am getting, pasting it into a java string trying to match again and it matches

Comment: regularExpressionExtractedFromDB is this save along with the double quotes ?

Comment: SpringLearner: I can always edit the question, no need for down votes and closing.

Comment: Mena: no, saved as \\w{3}-\\d{3}

Comment: @Sasha "no, saved as `\\w{3}-\\d{3}`"  and that is the problem ``\`` is special character in string so to create text representing ``\`` we need to write it with two ``\`` (one is used to escape another), but in database you don't need this additional ``\`` because it is storing text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Backslash symbol (`\`) in string constant is for escaping purposes.

For example

```
System.out.println("A\\B");
```

Will print `A\B`. In your database string must be `\w{3}-\d{3}`

Answer (score 1):

Here's an idea. Try:

```
System.out.println("\\www-\\ddd".matches(regularExpressionExtractedFromDB));
```

We expect that to be **true**.

The double backslashes are needed in a *string literal* to have the string contain a *single* backslash. The first backslash is an escape, the second one is the character being escaped. So the result is a single backslash character.

The value you get from the database would need to be

```
\w{3}-\d{3}
```

To be equivalent to the string literal "`\\w{3}-\\d{3}`". That value from the database is *not* being interpreted as a *string literal*, so the backslashes do *not* need to be "escaped".

```
System.out.println("\\w{3}-\\d{3}");
```